# What does this PHP notice mean?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $username="xxx";
    $password="xxx";
    $database="mobile_app";

    mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    foreach (array('courseid','roomChosen') as $varname) {
        $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['prequestion'])) {
        $roomquery = "
                     SELECT Room
                     FROM Room
                     WHERE
                     (Room = '".mysql_real_escape_string($roomChosen)."')
                     ";

        $roomnum = mysql_num_rows($roomresult = mysql_query($roomquery));
        mysql_close();

        if($roomnum ==0){
            $msg = "This Room is Invalid '$roomChosen'";
        } 
        else {
            $msg = "This Room is Valid '$roomChosen'";
        }
    }
    $d = array("msg" => $msg);
    echo json_encode($d);
?>
```

In this line of code near the bottom:

```
$d = array("msg" => $msg);
```

I am getting this notice:

> Notice: Undefined variable: msg in /u08877587/Mobile_app/room2.php on line 46
>   {"msg":null}

How do I fix this notice?

Comment: That the `$msg` variable isn't defined :P

Comment: Like the error message sais the $msg variable has not been set yet (undefined) . Before defining $d array define a $msg variable , ex. : $msg = 'msg is defined now';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place `$d = array("msg" =>$msg)` inside `if(isset($_POST['prequestion'])) {   }`

I.e:

```
if (isset($_POST['prequestion'])) 
{
    if($roomnum ==0)
    {
        $msg = "This Room is Invalid '$roomChosen'";
    } 
    else 
    {            
        $msg = "This Room is Valid '$roomChosen'";
    }


   $d = array("msg" => $msg);
   echo json_encode($d);    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In some `error_reporting` modes, PHP will give you a heads-up if you use a variable that hasn't been defined. You can do:

```
if(isset($msg) {
  $d = array("msg" => $msg);
}
```

or:

```
$d = array("msg" => @$msg);
```

or adjust your `error_reporting` configuration to not pass along `E_NOTICE` messages. There are times where this notice will help you find that you've done something like misspelled a variable, though.

Comment: This will solve the problem, but doesn't check to see if it got a $_POST variable for submit, which should encapsulate the whole function (or page in this case)

Comment: This has fixed the error but like Relic has mentioned it doesn't check to see if it got a $_POST variable for submit, why is this?

Comment: I answered the "How do I fix this notice?" bit. At the time, your code wasn't embedded into the post.

Comment: Yes I know you have answered the "How do I fix this notice" bit. This is just an extra question to solve. Don't worry you still get best answer. Just wanted a bit of help on what Relic has mentioned.

Comment: See @ZulkhaeryBasrul's answer below for that bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are never entering the `if (isset($_POST['prequestion']))` block, and so $msg is not being set. If that is a bug, try fixing that to solve your problems. Otherwise, you can do:

```
if ($msg) {
  $d = array("msg" => $msg);
}
```

Which will make sure `$msg` exists before you are trying to use it. Either that or set `$msg` to an empty string or something before the `if (isset($_POST['prequestion']))` statement.